# Passing object into classes, will they just be references to original?

Tags: java

This is the class which contains all `characters` and `objects` within a `level`.

`CollisionListener` is an interface, and `CollisionListener.beginContact()` is called whenever a character collides with another object.

I'm wondering, since I'm passing `level` into `CollisionListener`, does this mean 2 objects are stored in memory?

Or is `private Level level` inside `CollisionListener` just a reference to original `level`? How is this handled internally by JVM?

Since when I modify `level` inside `CollisionListener`, the original `level` is updated too.

```
public class Level extends World {

    private Player player;
    private Enemy enemy;

    public Level(){

        this.setContactListener(
            new CollisionListener(this));

        player = new Player();
        enemy = new Enemy();
    }

    /**
     * Move characters
     */
    public update(){

        player.update();
        enemy.update();
    }
}
```

This is an `interface`, thats added to my `Level` object. It needs a reference to a `Level` object so `level.doSomething()` can be invoked.

```
public class CollisionListener implements ContactListener{

    private Level level;

    public CollisionListener(Level level){

        this.level = level;
    }

    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

        this.level.doSomething();
    }

    /* other interface methods .. */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is private Level level inside CollisionListener just a reference to original level? How is this handled internally by JVM?

Of course it is. You always only deal with references to objects and copy those. In terms of C/C++ you could compare the references with pointers.

> Since when I modify level inside CollisionListener, the original level is updated too.

If you don't want that to happen, create a copy of the `Level` instance, e.g. by using the `Clonable` interface.